# Passing Variable from Codeigniter session class to FPDF class

Tags: php, codeigniter, session-variables, cfpdf

I'm having a bit of trouble setting the Header and Footer of a PDF I'm creating with FPDF and Codeigniter framework. in this code i can't echo $user variable to my Header. What must i do to get that variable ?.. 
The code for the class is the following:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
$user=$this->session->userdata('name');

class printFPDF extends FPDF{
    var $user;
    function userdata($user){
        $this->user=$user;
    }
    // Page header
    function Header(){
        global $user;
        // Arial bold 15
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
        // Move to the right
        $this->Cell(1);
        // Title
        $this->Cell(30,10,"Created by ".$this->user,0,0,'L');
        // Move to the right        
        $this->Cell(190);
        // Line break
        $this->Ln(15);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you included session library?

Comment: If he wouldn't have, he would have errors. You cannot ask a method on a non-object.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the variable anywhere to the PDF class.

```
$user=$this->session->userdata('name');
```

Here you correctly fetch the session from Codeigniter...inside Codeigniter. This line must be in a Controller, Model, whatever, but inside Codeigniter, since you're using it's native session library.

```
class printFPDF extends FPDF{
    var $user;
    function userdata($user){
        $this->user=$user;
```

}

I see you created inside that a custom method to assign an $user property. That's fine and right.

I don't know how you load the FDPF class, you should make it a library and load it using the $this->load->library() method in CI.

Now, whatever way you use to load the FPDF library inside CI, you should come out with an instance of the library object.

An example (let's pretend you didn't make it a library, and just included the class inside your controller, the same in which you fetched the $user variable from CI session)

```
$fpdf = new printFPDF();
```

Now you pass the custom made you created  the $user variable and the FPDF class will have it available:

```
$fpdf->userdata($user);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Damien Pirsy: It doesn't have to be inside CodeIgniter. You can always reference CodeIgniter instance anywhere in your project.

If you instance CodeIgniter in **$CI** variable, you have access to everything you have in controller, model, libraries, etc. Remember to use **$this->CI** instead of **$this** after doing this, like so:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');

class printFPDF extends FPDF{

    var $CI;

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

    function userdata($user){
        $this->CI->session->set_userdata('name', $user);
    }

    // Page header
    function Header(){
        // Arial bold 15
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
        // Move to the right
        $this->Cell(1);
        // Title
        $this->Cell(30,10,"Created by ".$this->CI->session->userdata('name'),0,0,'L');
        // Move to the right        
        $this->Cell(190);
        // Line break
        $this->Ln(15);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that, mine was a poor choice of words. Yours is another nice method of achieving the same thing. Personally, though, I would decouple the code, create the getter/setter for the user inside the FPDF class and load the class on demand. In this way you could use the class in another non-CI project and have it work fine without modifications in other environments